# Jquery each click invoke method to all tags at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind, quill

I am using Quill text editor and trying to insert internal links, so every time I click them I will scroll to a chosen position.

I have a jquery selector that find all those link and bind them to a "click" event.

My problem is every time I click on one of them the function is invoked to all of them one after the other.

why is it happening? why I don't see the funcion being invoked only once for that click?

```js
addLink() {
        const quill = this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();
        var range = quill.getSelection();
        var text = quill.getText(range.index, range.length);
        let position = range.index;
        quill.deleteText(range.index, range.length);
        quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(position, '<a href="' + position + '" target="_blank"><b>' + text + '</b></a>');
            let action = this.scrollTo
            $("a[target='_blank']").each(function () {
                var setTo = parseInt($(this).attr('href'));               
                $(this).bind("click", setTo, action);
            });
        }
    
    // if I have 3 links in my DOM and click one of them this will be invoked 3 times
    scrollTo(selectedTreeNode) {
        let scrollTo = selectedTreeNode.data 
        const quillRef = this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();
        quillRef.setSelection(scrollTo, 0);
    }
```

UPDATE

The reason it happened was I didn't know or took under consideration every bind is individual.
Every time I invoke Query.each I bind a new click action to the same anchor, that is why if I had 3 anchor the first one was invoked 3 times, the second one 2 time and the last one 1 time.

thanks

Comment: Consider adding a jsFiddle please or a live example.

Comment: Hay Ofir,
it took me a day and a half to give up and write this question, and 2 min later a figure what was the problem. 
To bad there is no way to inset gif here of me bang my head against the wall

Comment: It's a part of being a developer ;)
Consider adding an answer to your own question so if someone would have the same issue as you - they'd have a solution.

Comment: You are right, and so I did.
Thanks ofir